# A short clue for a clue

Tags: cryptic-clues

Please solve the following cryptic clue. Please cite supporting evidence.

*A short clue for a clue.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it a

> Cue

Which can be

> a hint or a clue

And

> is a shortened (fewer letters) form of the word clue